# Finding the best folder for all users on a Windows machine

Tags: c#, .net

We are making a game which will add a level editor feature soon. We want the user to be able to put levels he's downloaded in a folder and then play it in the game, without any hassle. So, we're looking for a folder that anybody can find, open, write, read, and is multiuser. On Windows Vista / 7, the folder /Users/Public/ look like a great candidate. However, It's not listed in the .net enum System.Environment.SpecialFolder. I have went through them all, and checked what they yield on different Windows versions, and none live up to my requirements.

I did find Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData, that kinda works, but that folder is hidden (C:\ProgramData) and I assume most users don't display hidden folders.

As it stands now, it looks like we'll have to settle for the personal documents folder, but we'd really like a multi user folder.

Anyone have any tips?

(Hard coding c:\Users\Public\ is out of the question, it will only work on english systems)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Doug Hennig** on [finding the path for C:\Users\Public](http://doughennig.blogspot.com/2007/01/finding-paths-for-special-folders.html):

> There isn’t a CSIDL value for this folder, but the environment variable PUBLIC points to it, so you can use GETENV('PUBLIC') to determine its location. By default, this variable contains C:\Users\Public in Windows Vista. The variable doesn't exist in Windows XP, so your code must handle the case where GETENV('PUBLIC') returns a blank value.
>
> Alternatively, you could use the parent of the folder specified by CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS, which gives C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents on XP and C:\Users\Public\Documents on Vista.

I think `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments` may be the right place for your files.

Comment: CommonDocuments sounds awesome, however it's .net 4.0, and I'm using mono 1.2.5 (which is like .net 2.0), so I'll have to make somthing like the above. Thanks.

Comment: CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS is the appropriate CSIDL value.

Answer (score 4):

The following should return `C:\Users\Public\Documents\` on Vista/Win7 and `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents` for previous OSes.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern int SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, int nFolder, IntPtr hToken,
 uint dwFlags, [Out] StringBuilder pszPath);

public string GetSharedDocsFolder() {
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 int CommonDocumentsFolder = 0x002e;

 SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, CommonDocumentsFolder, IntPtr.Zero, 0x0000, sb);
 return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Note that by default all users can write to this location, but users cannot write to files or folders created by a different user. If you want multiple non-administrator users to be able to modify the same file, you have to manage permissions explicitly - regardless of where you create the file/folder in the filing system.

Answer (score 1):

Could you put a folder in the application's directory, then create a shortcut to it for every user (when they first use the feature) in their home directory? I know it's not quite the "Universal" pre-existing folder you may have wanted, but would this work anyway?

Comment: You would need to be an administrator to work with the application's directory

Answer (score 0):

This may help. See this Post:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584%28VS.85%29.aspx
2. [Location of %allusersprofile% folder in Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784487/location-of-allusersprofile-folder-in-windows-vista)

In Windows Vista or later:

> %PUBLIC%  C:\Users\Public

In Windows XP:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%   C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
```